# How to set pretty url with .htaccess for different parameters

Tags: .htaccess, parameters, pretty-urls

I'm trying to set pretty URLs for my website. Thanks to @JonLin I managed to change site with two parameters. The other thing I want to do is make it work for one parameter as well. Here is the code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+devplus0/index\.php\?key=([^&]+)&lang=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRUle ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?key=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You can check the site prettyurl from http://www.devplus.co/english/about-us

Comment: What is one parameter URL you wan to enable?

Comment: $_GET['key'] is the on I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one param, add:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+devplus0/index\.php\?key=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRUle ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]
```